# Gust Rules Clarification

Tags: dandelions

I'd just like to clear up the **Gust** rules in [Dandelions](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/347883/dandelions) by BoardGameTables, which I think is based on a Japanese game called [Birth](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/157487/birth).

The rules say:

> If you plant in a garden with other players' dice matching your value, move all the matching dice to one adjacent garden.

I want to be super clear that this means what I think it does.

- You can never move your own dice
- You have to move all matching opponents' dice
- All moved dice must move to the same (adjacent) garden